# Hairpins vertical aligment using Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to adjust the vertical aligment of hairpins. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\begin{document}
\centering
\hspace*{2.5cm}\begin{music}
    %\input musixps
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract %inicia el fragmento musical
    \NOTEs\icresc\zchar{13}{\pp}\wh{c}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\p}\wh{d}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\mp}\wh{e}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\mf}\wh{f}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\f}\wh{g}\tcresc\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\ff}\wh{j}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\icresc\zchar{13}{\f}\wh{g}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\mf}\wh{f}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\mp}\wh{e}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\p}\wh{d}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\pp}\wh{c}\tdecresc\en
    \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
 \end{music}
 
\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of the officially sanctioned method, but a `\raisebox` can provide the required fix.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2.8cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, marginparwidth=0cm, marginparsep=0cm, headheight=13.6pt, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\begin{document}
\centering
\hspace*{2.5cm}\begin{music}
    %\input musixps
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract %inicia el fragmento musical
    \NOTEs\icresc\zchar{13}{\pp}\wh{c}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\p}\wh{d}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\mp}\wh{e}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\mf}\wh{f}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\f}\wh{g}\raisebox{-12pt}{\tcresc}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\ff}\wh{j}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\icresc\zchar{13}{\f}\wh{g}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\mf}\wh{f}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\mp}\wh{e}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\p}\wh{d}\en\bar
    \NOTEs\zchar{13}{\pp}\wh{c}\raisebox{-12pt}{\tdecresc}\en
    \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
 \end{music}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats nice. Used raisebox with musixtex many times …

Comment: Actually, this is not the MusiXTeX way, which is the answer of user206750, see MusiXTeX manual paragraph 10.7 (page 53-54).

Answer (score 7):

Just replace your lines

```
\NOTEs\zchar{13}{\f}\wh{g}\tcresc\en\bar
```

and

```
\NOTEs\zchar{13}{\pp}\wh{c}\tdecresc\en
```

by this:

```
\NOTEs\zchar{13}{\f}\wh{g}\zcharnote N{\tcresc}\en\bar
```

and this:

```
\NOTEs\zchar{13}{\pp}\wh{c}\zcharnote N{\tdecresc}\en
```

according to chapter 10.7 p. 53 of musixdoc.pdf